# Getting npm to work with spacemacs in daemon mode

Tags: emacs, systemd, spacemacs

I am trying to get lsp (that depends on npm) to work with my emacsclient.

After some tinkering, I manage to get my lsp to work by running `. /usr/share/nvm/nvm.sh` then `emacs --daemon` in an interactive shell manually.

However, I do not want to run the `emacs --daemon` manually in the interactive shell.

Below shows what I have tried so far, will appreciate if someone can point out why what i have been doing is not correct.

**Attempt #1** Updating the systemd unit file:

adding `ExecStartPre=/bin/bash /usr/share/nvm/nvm.sh` to `emacs.service`

**Result** `(executable-find "node")` returns `nil`

**Attempt #2** Add a hardcode PATH into `.spacemacs`:

`(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("~/.local/share/nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/bin")))`

**Result** `(executable-find "node")` returns `"~/.local/share/nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/bin/node"` but it still to connect to the lsp server

**Attempt #3** Use bspwm to autolaunch emacs instead of systemd:

Appended `$(. "/usr/share/nvm/nvm.sh" && emacs --daemon)` to `bspwmrc`

**Result** `(executable-find "node")` returns `"nil"`

Answer (score 1):

For now, I will stick to attemp #2.

I realize that it did'nt work if i use `~` instead the `/home/user`

Thus the following should work.

```
  (setq exec-path
        (append exec-path
                (list (concat user-home-directory ".local/share/nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/bin"))))
```

For now, this is the best solution that I manage to find.

Comment: `expand-file-name` or `file-truename` are alternatives

Answer (score 0):

**Attempt #4** Update `zshrc`:

```
if [[ -z $(pgrep emacs) ]]; then
    . "/usr/share/nvm/nvm.sh" &> /dev/null 
    emacs --daemon &> /dev/null
fi
```

**Result** Finally works, but it will result in some delay for the first startup of my zsh.

Is there a better workaround other than this?

Ideally, the daemon is preferred to start using systemd otherwise, during reboot, it wouldn't stop gracefully :(

Comment: there is `emacsclient -ca ""`, not sure how well it works on windows - on ubuntu I set a keyboard custom `"bash -c 'emacsclient -ca ""'`, since I find systemd process more trouble when tinkering with config

Comment: hmm, this will only launch the emacsclient.

However, the issue is that node's path is not added into the emacs path because I am using `nvm` which lazy loads the path.

Comment: oh, for some reason I thought you were on windows. If you are running under Gnome, if you source your package managers in ~/.profile (get rid of .bash_profile and the like) then node should be sourced at login (at least, this is what works for me on ubuntu 18) -- but different window managers source login scripts in different orders/times so YMMV